# Objective-C What's the proper way of declaring and initializing a C array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing Objective-C class ivar that is a C array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530367/initializing-objective-c-class-ivar-that-is-a-c-array)

I'm trying to declare a C array in my @interface like this:

```
 @interface Path : NSObject{
   float pathPoints[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;};
 }
```

This way I get "Expected ; at the end of declaration list"

Then I try

```
@interface Path : NSObject{
  float pathPoints[10];
}

@implementation Path
-(id)init{
 if (self=[super init])
  pathPoints={0.5,1.0,....};//Here I get "Expected expression" warning

 ..............
}
```

This time I get "Expected expression" warning. Now, what's the proper way of having a C array as an ivar, initialize it with predefined number of elements and use it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initializing Objective-C class ivar that is a C array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530367/initializing-objective-c-class-ivar-that-is-a-c-array). See also [How to use a C-type array as an ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834137/)

Comment: Thank you very much. So what I understood from the thread that I have to create a local one and sort of load the ivar with its values. But I can't still understand why I get those errors.

Comment: You can't set the value of any ivar in the `@interface`, but the initializer `{0.5, 1.0, ...}` isn't allowed except at a variable's declaration. Since you have to declare ivars in the interface, you must initalize another variable, then copy the memory over to the ivar.

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me why I can't declare the C Array at interface and then initialize it in the implementation part? With normal primitive types and Objective-C classes this is what I do all the time.

Comment: This isn't an ObjC problem really. C doesn't allow arrays to be initialized like that after declaration. I'm honestly not sure why, but notice that `int main(int argc, char * argv[]){ int a[10]; a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; return 0; }` produces the same error.

Comment: Hmm, thank you so much.I hope you'd transport all you comments, maybe mixed altogether, into an answer